# Subsetting and editing array of objects in Javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, javascript-objects

I have an array of object in Javascript that I want to subset based on key-value matches. In principle I want to access my array `js_obj`, change some objects where `cond` is true and then move on.

Let's say the array looks like this

```
js_obj = [{
    word: "airport",
    pic: "<img id='pic' src='../images/location/airport.png'/>",
    cat: "location",
    type: "undetermined"
}, {
    word: "station",
    pic: "<img id='pic' src='../images/location/station.png'/>",
    cat: "location",
    type: "undetermined"
}]
```

I now want to access `js_obj` where `.word == "station"` and of this selected object I want to change `.type` to `"type_abc"`.

I was able to use `each` and select the object where the condition applies and change its `.type` as wanted, but I would like to do this within the original array. I do not simply want to filter out this object but find it, edit it, and leave the array in the modified state.
I found related posts referring to underscore.js but I think I didn't know which method to look for.

Can anybody help me with this indexing/subsetting problem?

Comment: Unless you've actually cloned the array, changing a property in the objects does change the array ?

Comment: @adeneo That wouldn't be a problem. But it's mainly that I want to maintain the array structure. The actual name is not too important really.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looping the array, checking the condition and modifying will keep it in the original array:

```
function modifyArrOfObjs(arr, key, condition, updateKey, updateValue) {
    arr.forEach(function(obj) {
        if (obj[key] == condition) {
            obj[updateKey] = updateValue;
        }
    });
}

modifyArrOfObjs(js_obj, "word", "station", "type", "type_abc");
```